# How do I use wild character in MongoDB while using Update?

Tags: mongodb

How do I use wild character in MongoDB while use Update
I want to do like below in mongo db is it possible to write it.

```
update emp set sal=sal*2 where ename like '%Pr%';
```

`emp` is the collection name

columns: `ename`, `eno`, `sal`

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regexp for your wildcard search, but you have to do the update client-side, because mongoDB is not able to access the content of another field (or the field's content itself) while updating:

```
db.emp.find( { ename: /Pr/ } ).forEach( function (x) {   
    x.sal = x.sal * 2; 
    db.emp.save( x );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In MongoDB 2.6 you will be able to do that update enirely server-side using the new $mul operator. As of the time of this posting 2.6 is still in pre-relase; you can check the [MongoDB download page](http://www.mongodb.org/downloads) for availability. Check the [release notes](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/release-notes/2.6/) for a complete list of changes and new features.

Also note that you should use an anchored regexp query, that is one that begins with ^, if you know that the string you are searching for is at the beginning of the field. Anchored regexp queries are more efficient because they can use an index and avoid a table scan.

Here is the query with these two changes:

```
db.emp.update({ename: /^Pr/}, {$mul: {sal: 2}}, {multi: true})
```